# jQuery - How many animations are running

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

With the following code I try to wait till no animation is running any more.

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> animationLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
    {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $(':animated').length").toString().equals("0");
    }
};

DriverProvider.getWait().until(animationLoad);
```

The code doesn't wait. The apply funtion returns true every time. Even the animation is still running. How can I solve this?

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: I cant't decode your hint.

Comment: you shouldn't have to included javascript in your tag while posting question

Comment: But there is a javaScript string inside executeScript, isn't it?

Comment: What is throw if only get length of animated elements in line 9?

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor)DriverProvider.getDriver()).executeScript("return $(':animated').length"); - Oject's values is every time 0. No exception is thrown.

Comment: is the animation running in the same frame you are executing the script? When you visit the site manually and execute your javascript, does it return something else then 0?

Comment: I never changed the frame. How can I execute javascript when I visit the site manually?

Comment: Most browsers have so called "developer tools" which include a console that lets you enter javascript commands.

Comment: Also when I tried developer tools...every time returning 0.

Comment: $(':animated').length - seems returning 0 on any page. Any hints? Do someone have a page where this command is not returning 0?

Comment: The selector `$(':animated').length` returns the count of animations created with JQuery. Animations created with some other code, with a CSS transition or with a Gif image are not included in the count.